# Twitter Bootstrap Popovers - how to make them stay?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

RE: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers

My popovers are triggered by `hover` event. When the popover appears, there are a couple of links I have put in the popovers that I'd like my users to have a chance to click. However, when the mouse pointer leaves the popover's hot spot and attempts to enter the popover area, the popover disappears.

Is there a way to make the popover stay?

Comment: Could you post the relevant HTML/JS?

Answer (score 2):

You could set the `container` element of your popover to the element that triggered the popover.

#### [Demo in fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LNB5W/)

**HTML**:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger popover-dismiss" 
        data-toggle="popover" title="Dismissible popover"
        data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging.">
    Dismissible popover
</button>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
$('.popover-dismiss').popover({
    trigger: 'hover',
    container: '.popover-dismiss'
})
```

**CSS**:

```
.popover-dismiss .popover {
    color: #333 ;
}
```

Unfortunately, you'll need to add CSS because in the example `button` CSS overrides `popover` CSS.

Comment: Clever.  I'm sure I'll find a use for that someday. +1

Answer (score 1):

I dig the @holt answer, but also wanted to point out that there's a delay option for both show and hide:

```
$('.popover').popover({
    trigger: 'hover',
    delay: { hide: 3000 }
})
```